# Unable to add a service reference - locked/read only

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Whenever I go to add a service reference I get the error:

> Failed to add Service Reference 'Servicereference1.reference'
>   Error: Unable to check out the current file. The file may be read-only or locked, or you may need to check the file out manually.

I already had a service reference in the project, but it broke somehow and gave me an error that stated:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract (servicename)

The endpoints in both the web.config and the service reference config were the same (localhost)

I also could not update that reference as I would get the same 'unable to check out current file' error.

EDIT: The problem isn't native to just this project. I tried to make a new, totally separate project, and add a service reference to that and I got the same error.

Comment: I think this has to do with your version control system (VSS or TFS maybe?) having the file locked than it does with the inability to add a service reference.

Comment: Running vs2013 as administrator worked for me (as mentioned in Pranav's answer below)

Answer (score 102):

I had the same error - what I found, was that there are problems if you have source control plugin "Microsoft Git provider" selected (my WCF solution **was not** added to source control!) and you try to add service reference.

1. set source control plugin to None

   - go to TOOLS > Options > Source Control.
2. add service reference
3. set the source control plugin to the original value

Comment: This is still not fixed in VS 2013 Update 4.  I can duplicate this every time when trying to add a service reference.  I use Git as my source control provider.   These steps are a workaround, or alternatively, you can shut down VS and re-run it as an Administrator.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer.  This is precisely what happened to me.  After I switched from "Git Provider" to "None", I was able to add a Service Reference immediately, without having to restart, run in admin mode, or any of that stuff.

Comment: This error seems to have multiple cause.Check this
https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/visual-studio-unable-to-checkout-the-current-file/
This solution might work for some people.

Comment: The link is "Page not Found"

Comment: @JackFrost Hmm... seems they have removed the page recently (don't know why), but all the necessary information is in the answer anyway.

Comment: For those who don't know, to "set source control plugin to None", go to TOOLS > Options > Source Control.

Comment: This issue is still happening in VS 2015 Update 2. Disabling the Source Control solve the issue. I think is something related with the git plugin.

Comment: 2021 and we still have this bug in VS 2019.

Comment: Same error occurred in VS 2019. Solved with this solution.

Answer (score 29):

I know this has been answered, but before trying everything else in the answers, restart visual studio.
This just happened to me and 4 other people in my WCF class. Seems to be a problem with visual studio 2013 and not 2012.

Comment: In my case, it seems related to adding the service to a brand-new solution.  Restarting VS between project creation and adding the service seems to work fine.

Comment: @Jeremy same for me. I needed to restart after creating a new solution.

Comment: Just happened to me with VS 2012. :)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 11):

As you have already cleared there is no source control involved(which seems to be cause of problem to me), you can try these steps:

1. Make sure if you copy paste from location where there was source control then remove source control specific files.
2. Make sure folder is not locked & also is not read-only. If it is so, then remove read-only from the folder.
3. Make sure visual studio is not in debugging mode while adding reference.
4. If above not works, close visual studio & restart it.
5. Make sure Visual Studio is started as "Run as Administrator".
6. Finally if all above doesn't work try restart machine.

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: I've restarted my machine and visual studio a few times already, that did not help. The folder where the service references are to be added is set to 'read-only', but I'm on Windows 7, every folder has the attribute set like this: http://i.imgur.com/Bm1CSOy.png and it was not an issue before.

Comment: I found that running VS as Administrator seemed to help as well.

Comment: I just restarted Visual Studio it worked even it was in debugging mode. Thanks

Comment: Running as admin worked for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, No. 5 Make sure Visual Studio is started as "Run as Administrator". It works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it's a bit late, but if someone has the same problem, I solved it running VS2013 as administrator.

Answer (score 5):

> Go to **Debug** menu and click on (**Options and Settings**)

[image: debug]

> Select **Source Control**.
>
> > Under **Current Source** ControlPlug-in drop down select **none**

[image: none]

> Then click **ok** to save chnages,Now you can add service reference.

Answer (score 3):

Oddly enough I was experiencing this in VS 2019, using git source control. I was able to resolve this by simply cleaning and rebuilding the project containing the service reference...

EDIT: If you already have a service reference that you're attempting to update you might have to delete it and add it again

Comment: Same here, thanks for the tip. Worked for me in VS 2019.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was related to source control but I found an easy work-around. Open the App.config file and make any change and save it. This unlocked the file and allowed me to add the service reference.

Comment: This worked for me in Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.11.25

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some Visual studio file has gone corrupted. Try deleteing the reference completely then generate the reference using svcutil {http://{service}/metadataEndpoint} ( I assume it is WCF) or (use wsdl.exe for webservices), then get the client proxy and put it in the project to use it. See if that works fine.

Comment: Which reference should I delete? There are no current service references in the project.

Comment: Can you try using the svcutil and see if all works?  try restarting machine as well.. I have seen that error before and I think it was due to some plugin installed- do you have any VS extensions installed?

Comment: The problem came about after I installed Teleriks UI for ASP.NET package. But it was not immediately after; my application worked fine for several hours until I received this error.

Comment: Check that there  are no files obvious in your app data profile folder. May be clearing the profile and trying again fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Shutting down your default source control to add reference is horrible.  @ScottG said above, and does work.. just start VS as administrator - that works, and you dont have to mess with your environment.  VS 2013 UP-5 still has this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your files are read only, if yes remove the read only attribute and restart the visual studio and try to add service reference.
it worked for me like this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, your folder in IIS where your services put (I mean the physical file; .svc) is not open or even selected in file manager. It's work for me, but before I almost went mad to find error.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I am last here and spend 1 day to search the solution , nothing was wrong in my code and I tried multiple times restart machine , close reopen visual studio but nothing worked .In my case there were some update in visual studio 2019 and that was causing the issue. After installing the update I was able to update the service reference. Hope this will be helpful for some one .

Comment: If possible, would you add to your solution the version of Visual Studio 2019 that had the problem, and the version of Visual Studio 2019 that you updated to which solved the problem?