# locked files of .net core project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I am trying to update a service reference in the project, but it broke somehow and gave me the following error:

[image]

The list in solution explorer shows all the files locked.
The only solution I have found so far is to move the project folder to another folder. But every time I m updating the service reference the files are being locked again. I m using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.18. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you are somehow colliding with your subversioning software... WHich one are you using? GIT, SVN or other?

Comment: That's a message from your version control software. Which version control do you use? Subversion? TFS? Git doesn't lock files

Comment: I m using Git. None of the solution on stackoverflow worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148552/unable-to-add-a-service-reference-locked-read-only

Comment: "Set source control plugin to None", go to TOOLS > Options > Source Control. Doesn't this work for you?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT it worked but I had to restart the visual studio. After restarting VS, I updated the service reference and I had to change source control to GIT again. But this is just a workaround, not a permanent solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use FileStream.Lock() method for this purpose or maybe this could help you to achieve your goal.

take a look this link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.lock?view=net-6.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).